# Updating the docker(18.09.0) causes an error

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

After updating the docker to version 18.09.0, I get the following error(Virtual server with Ubuntu 18.04):

`Nov 09 20:53:52 localhost.localdomain modprobe[663]: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open buitin file '/lib/modules/4.15.0/modules.builtin.bin`

`Nov 09 20:53:52 localhost.localdomain modprobe[663]: modprobe: FATAL: Module overlay not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0`

`uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.15.0 #1 SMP Wed May 23 10:04:13 MSK 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Also on LXC container (with Ubuntu 18.04) in Majaro

`Nov 09 21:06:38 Ubuntu modprobe[5393]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.14.78-1-MANJARO/modules.dep.bin'
Nov 09 21:06:38 Ubuntu modprobe[5393]: modprobe: FATAL: Module overlay not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.78-1-MANJARO`

`uname -a
Linux Ubuntu 4.14.78-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 21 07:57:51 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`docker -v
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to override a portion of the containerd service file:

```
systemctl edit containerd.service
```

Then insert the following and save it:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=
```

After that you'll be able to get docker to start.
For reference: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/475#issuecomment-437373774

Essentially your systemd file needs to have the ExecStartPre value cleared, best to use an override file so an upgrade will properly update the main file.